# Raster Statistics of Fire Driven Forest Loss within shapefile

Tags: python, rasterio, zonal-statistics, rioxarray, geocube

I have two inputs,
a) shapefile, which I am reading in as a geodataframe, download here: https://we.tl/t-QxfgtLWOVN
b) raster data from -  GFW Fire Driven Forest Loss dataset, download here: https://glad.umd.edu/users/Alexandra/Fire_GFL_data/2001-21/NAM_fire_forest_loss_2001-21_annual.tif

```
import geopandas as gpd
import xarray as xr
import rasterio
import rioxarray
from rasterstats import zonal_stats
    
shapefile = gpd.read_file("/pathtoshapefile.shp")

fdfl = rioxarray.open_rasterio("pathto/NAM_fire_forest_loss_2001-21_annual.tif"))
```

I wish to calculate the annual area of fire-driven loss within the shapefile. 30x30m pixels within the raster are assigned a value, where (from documentation) "codes 1-21 correspond to 2001-2021 loss".

I want to calculate the area of the raster that overlaps with my shapefile; for each value within the raster between 1-21, outputting as a CSV, in the format:

```
1, Xarea
2, Xarea
3, Xarea
...
21, Xarea
```

Files can be downloaded from above, bounty goes to an exact solution. I am working in Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: It would be better if you can provide the files and complete code to reproduce the error.

Comment: Added links to shp and raster, full code is there, thanks!

Comment: The shapefile download has expired.

Comment: @MoreMeowbell I have replaced the link, thanks

Comment: @Stuey17 Shawn's answer is pretty good, what else are you looking for? Got the shapefile by the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using `rasterstats`, which is very efficient with large rasters like the one you have. Your shapefile link is stale so I used one with some random AOIs.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio
from rasterstats import zonal_stats

shapes = gpd.read_file('aois.shp')
tif_file = './NAM_fire_forest_loss_2001-21_annual.tif'

# Ensure CRS matches
with rasterio.open(tif_file) as src:
    tif_crs = src.crs

if shapes.crs != tif_crs:
    shapes = shapes.to_crs(tif_crs)

# Get the pixel counts for each aoi in the shapefile
# See https://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/manual.html#working-with-categorical-rasters
all_counts = []

for shape in shapes.itertuples():
    shape_counts = zonal_stats(vectors = shape.geometry, 
                               raster = tif_file,
                               categorical = True)[0]

    # Map the 0-21 integers to years.
    for pixel_value, count in shape_counts.items():
        
        if pixel_value==0:
            # Skip 0 since it means no forest loss.
            continue 
        
        # codes 1-21 correspond to 2001-2021 loss
        year = pixel_value + 2000
        
        # Compute area with 30x30m pixels.
        area_m2 = count * 30 * 30 
        
        all_counts.append({
            'area_id':shape.area_id,
            'year': year,
            'area_m2': area_m2
            })

# Save to csv
pd.DataFrame(all_counts).to_csv('area_forest_loss.csv', index=False)
```

If you do not want results for individual shapes in your shapefile, then you can discard the for loop like so

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio
from rasterstats import zonal_stats

shapes = gpd.read_file('aois.shp')
tif_file = './NAM_fire_forest_loss_2001-21_annual.tif'

# Ensure CRS matches
with rasterio.open(tif_file) as src:
    tif_crs = src.crs

if shapes.crs != tif_crs:
    shapes = shapes.to_crs(tif_crs)

# Get the pixel counts for each aoi in the shapefile
# See https://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/manual.html#working-with-categorical-rasters
all_counts = []

shape_counts = zonal_stats(vectors = shapes, 
                           raster = tif_file,
                           categorical = True)[0]

# Map the 0-21 integers to years.
for pixel_value, count in shape_counts.items():
    
    if pixel_value==0:
        # Skip 0 since it means no forest loss.
        continue 
    
    # codes 1-21 correspond to 2001-2021 loss
    year = pixel_value + 2000
    
    # Compute area with 30x30m pixels.
    area_m2 = count * 30 * 30 
    
    all_counts.append({
        'year': year,
        'area_m2': area_m2
        })

# Save to csv
pd.DataFrame(all_counts).to_csv('area_forest_loss.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thank you for the commented code too, I can understand this.

Comment: Could you please add how to map a 0 value to the years in which there are no forest loss? EG 2003 : 500, 2004 : 0

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking for geocube. Here is an example of doing zonal statistics will rasterio and geocube:

https://corteva.github.io/geocube/stable/examples/zonal_statistics.html

```py
out_grid = make_geocube(
    vector_data=shapefile,
    measurements=["mukey"], # unique ID column
    like=fd1, # ensure the data are on the same grid
)

out_grid["forest_loss"] = (fd1.dims, fd1.values, fd1.attrs, fd1.encoding)

grouped = out_grid.drop("spatial_ref").groupby(out_grid.mukey)
grid_mean = grouped.mean().rename({"forest_loss": "forest_loss_mean"})
```

Comment: My kernel dies when I try to run this

Comment: Is it due to memory limitations?

Answer (score 1):

if i understand it right, you could also use QGIS for this

1. clip Raster by mask layer. Use your shp as mask layer
2. Polygonize (Raster to Vektor) the clipped Raster
3. Dissolve (use the Value of the Raster as Dissolve Field)
4. Calculate Area with Field Calculator Expression: $area

[image: attributeTable]

Comment: Thanks! :) But I want an automated, repeatable process in python